# SBPL Non-Holonomic Motion Primitives

Tags: ros, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not having much luck creating motion primitives that follow non-holonomic type constraints.  I keep running into the issue that I have no end poses that match to a start pose.  Is there anyone willing to share a modified .m that they were able to implement these types of mprims?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60348/sbpl-non-holonomic-motion-primitives/) by [blake11](https://answers.ros.org/users/4647/blake11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsafonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4799/rsafonov/) on 2013-05-01**:
Are you still looking for the answer? If yes, can you please provide more details about your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a similar problem. I have a dynamical model of a boat (Nomoto turn-rate model, with side-slip and linear speed dynamics added) that I am trying to use to generate motion primitives. As I understand, ideally I should choose primitives that end up in specific grid cells. However, as mentioned by Martin, it is not necessarily easily possible with the non-holonomic model I am using.

In my case, currently I am applying certain control actions for a specific period of time to forward propagate the dynamic model. Then whatever end-pose I end up with, I map it into its corresponding grid cell. Depending on discretization used, this approach will result in discontinuities at end grid points.

I was wondering if anyone else has come across such a scenario. I would certainly appreciate an input. Thank you very much for your help!

---

Originally posted by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) with karma: 287 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0